# reducer isn't triggered (redux-promise with axios)

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, redux-promise

I'm trying to make an api call in action with axios and pass the results of it to the reducer.
Though action is triggered, reducer isn't. And I can't understand why.

Here's the component that should make api call before mounting

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

//actions
import { getPost } from '../actions/';


class PostShow extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);

 }

 componentWillMount() {
  getPost(this.props.params.id);
 }
 

 render() {
  console.log(this.props.activePost);
  return (
   <div>
    <h1> hello from a post</h1>
   </div>
  )
 }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
 return {
  activePost: state.posts.activePost
 }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
 return bindActionCreators({
  getPost
 }, dispatch);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostShow);
```

Here's my action

```js
import axios from 'axios';

import { FETCH_POSTS, SEND_POST, FETCH_POST } from './types';

const ROOT_URL = 'http://reduxblog.herokuapp.com/api';
const API_KEY = '?key=qwerty';

export function fetchPosts() {
 const req = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/posts${API_KEY}`);

 return {
  type: FETCH_POSTS,
  payload: req
 }
}

export function sendPost(props) {
 const req = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/posts${API_KEY}`, props);

 return {
  type: SEND_POST,
  payload: req
 }

}

export function getPost(id) {
 console.log('action triggered');
 const req = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/posts/${id}${API_KEY}`);

 return {
  type: FETCH_POST,
  payload: req
 }
}
```

And here's my reducer

```js
import { FETCH_POSTS, FETCH_POST } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
 allPosts: [],
 activePost: null
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
  case FETCH_POSTS:
   return {
    ...state,
    allPosts: action.payload.data
   };
  case FETCH_POST:
   console.log('reducer triggered');
   return {
   ...state,
   activePost: action.payload.data
  };
  default:
   return state;
 }
}
```

As a result I see 'action triggered' coming from console.log in action, and null coming from console.log in component, and no console.log from the reducer, so it's not triggered and I have no data to render in my component.
Though I make a request and get a response from server with the data, it doesn't go to the reducer. (moreover case FETCH_POSTS works fine and I can render a list of posts, but not a particular one).

"axios": "^0.17.0"
"redux-promise": "^0.5.3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `this.props.getPost` in `componentDidMount` instead of `getPost`.

Connect sends bound action creator to component as a prop